# Finding the dimensionality of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, multidimensional-array

Given some object `o`, I need to find its dimensionality (eg: for `int[x][y][z]` the dimensionality is `3`), I figured that any appropriate method would be in the class of the object.

```
int dimensionality = o.getClass().getName().indexOf('L');
```

works, but its source refers to a native method, so I'm left getting the answer from a string, rather than directly.

If anyone knows a better way of doing this it would be appreciated (although more for the sake of curiosity than necessity).

Comment: How many dimensions in `{{{},{}},{}}`?

Comment: The dimensionality of {{{},{}},{}} is either two or undefined.

Comment: If you're asking why I want the dimensionality of the object, I'm dealing with arrays of float data in either two or three dimensions; if you're asking why I'm calling indexOf('L') on the name of the class, the names of array classes begin with "[[[L" where the number of rectangular opening brackets is the dimensionality of the array class.

Comment: How can you calculate something that you can't even unambiguously define?

Comment: You can, but not always for arrays of the Object component type. For all other types it is unambiguous.

Comment: OK. How about `{{{1,2},{1,2,3}},{1,2,3,4}};`? Only primitives are used. Java allows ragged arrays of any type.

Comment: It doesn't matter, in order to put {1, 2, 3, 4} and {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}} into the same array, the component type of the array must be Object.

Comment: Component type of **any** so called *multidimensional* `array` is just another `array`. There's nothing here to argue about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution using [`Class.isArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray%28%29):

```
static int getDimensionality(final Class<?> type) {
    if (type.isArray()) {
        return 1 + getDimensionality(type.getComponentType());
    }
    return 0;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDimensionality(int.class));       // 0
    System.out.println(getDimensionality(int[].class));     // 1
    System.out.println(getDimensionality(int[][].class));   // 2
    System.out.println(getDimensionality(int[][][].class)); // 3
}
```

Although as [PM 77-1 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864655/finding-the-dimensionality-of-an-array-in-java/20864702#comment31304427_20864655), this is not truly a measure of *dimensionality* but of the depth of a jagged array in terms of its static type. There are no true multidimensional arrays in Java, just arrays of arrays.

Comment: In most scenarios you'll be dealing with arrays of a defined type, rather than Objects. Irrespective of java's use of true multidimensional arrays, dimensionality is defined in most use cases (eg: T[][][]...[] has a unique dimensionality value, although Object[][][]...[] may not).

Answer (score 0):

If the array is more complex e.g.

```
Object[] oa = new Object[] {1, new Object[] {"a", new int[] {5, 6, 7}, "c"}, 3};
```

getComponentType is not gonna work. In that case you could determine the maximum nesting depth like this

```
static int maxDim(Object[] oa) {
    int maxDim = 0;
    for(Object o: oa) {
        if(o instanceof int[] || o instanceof long[] || o instanceof short[] ||
           o instanceof byte[] || o instanceof float[] ||
           o instanceof double[] || o instanceof boolean[]) {
            maxDim = Math.max(maxDim, 1);
        } else if(o instanceof Object[]) {
            maxDim = Math.max(maxDim, maxDim((Object[])o));
        }
    }
    return maxDim + 1;
}
```

Comment: The dimensionality of the given example is 1, since `oa[1]` is of type `Object`, not `int[]`.  Even though `oa[1]` refers to an `int[]`, one cannot subscript the inner array without typecasting `oa[1]` to `int[]` first.